# Using operator[] to access a private std::map of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, stdmap

I have a class with a private std::map of unique_ptr:

```
class MyClass{
std::map <KeyType, std::unique_ptr<my_type>> my_map;
...
};
```

I chose unique_ptr because my_map is the sole owner of my_type objects.

I would like to expose an operator[] public member function to access (perfect forwarding) my_map.
Something like:

```
// my_class is of type MyClass
auto ptr = my_type_factory(...); // my_type_factory returns a std::unique_ptr<my_type>
....
my_class[1] = std::move(auto_ptr);
```

I have tried with various possible definitions of operator[] :

```
class MyClass{
....
public:
auto operator[](KeyType && key) { return my_map[std::forward<KeyType>(key)]; } 
// or return & my_map[...];
};
```

but it doesn't work, in the end I am always invoking the deleted copy constructor of unique_ptr.

Just to move forward, if I move my_map to the public interface I have made all my tests pass, but this is cheating of course, since I am trying to refine my modern C++ skills and I think there is some principle which I have not grokked yet with unique_ptr and move.

So my question is: how do I use std::unique_ptr's in a private std::map?

Comment: @LogicStuff: Can't be dupe of that one, just by the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return a reference.

```
auto & operator[](KeyType && key) { return my_map[std::forward<KeyType>(key)]; }
```

Comment: But wouldn't that also hit the deleted default ctor of a unique_ptr?

Comment: @einpoklum Default constructor of `unique_ptr` is not deleted, only copy constructor and copy assignment operator are. It will be initialized with nullptr.

Comment: That works, great. Could you please elaborate so that I can understand better? In my idea the operator[] called on my_map was already returning a reference and I expected that the "auto" was already a reference. What am I missing?

Comment: @Francesco `auto` type deduction rules would drop a reference and produce `std::unique_ptr<my_type>`, it is `decltype(auto)` that would produce exactly the same reference type as you expected. I guess this is rather counter intuitive.

Comment: do you mean decltype(my_map[a_key]) ? or decltype(auto)? Can you give me a  pointer (to the standard,a blog post or to a question here on SO for this behaviour)? Or, I will ask a question about it. Very counter-intuititive for me.

Comment: @Francesco I mean `decltype(auto) operator[](`. There are already several questions asking this around SO.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, maybe you could add to the answer so that it will be fully self-contained without references to comments. decltype(auto) is really funny, if you think about it. Auto is deducing the return type and decltype is the type that auto is deducing.... yet they are different.

Comment: decltype(auto) forces compiler to use decltype type guessing instead of template type guessing, which is used for auto.